# Parse XML document without knowing it's structure in Java

Tags: java, xml, stax

I'd like a way to parse an XML Document without knowing it's document structure or hardcoding it's node/element names to return me a Map in Key, Value pairing.

I'm currently parsing an XML document using stAx, the current implementation works but interestingly enough it's not parsing the whole document. Somehow it's skipping data.

By looking at the XML Document and the test output, you'll notice not all the values are printed. What could I be missing?

Code:

```
public Map<String, String> p(File file) throws Exception {

    Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String,String>();
    XMLStreamReader xr = XMLInputFactory.newInstance().createXMLStreamReader(new FileInputStream(file));


    while(xr.hasNext()) {

        int e = xr.next();
        if (e == XMLStreamReader.START_ELEMENT) {
            String name = xr.getLocalName();
            xr.next();
            String value = null;
            try {
                value = xr.getText();
            } catch (IllegalStateException exep) {
                exep.printStackTrace();
            }
            map.put(name, value);
        } 
    }
    return map;
}



@Test
public void test() throws Exception, FactoryConfigurationError, Exception {
    File f = new File("xmlDir/request.xml");
    Map<String,String> map = p(f);

    // Print all Key/Value pairs
    for(Map.Entry<String, String> entry: map.entrySet()) {
        String key = entry.getKey(); 
        String value = entry.getValue();
        logger.debug("Key: "+key);
        logger.debug("Value: "+value);
    }

    Assert.assertEquals(map.get("MonthlyPlanPremiumAmtPP"), "136");
    Assert.assertEquals(map.get("MonthlyAdvancedPTCAmtPP"), "125");
    Assert.assertEquals(map.get("AdjustedGrossIncomeAmt"), "22000");
    Assert.assertEquals(map.get("TotalExemptionsCnt"), "1");
}
```

Output:

```
2015-08-18 16:21:44,408 : Key: IRS1095A
2015-08-18 16:21:44,409 : Value: 

2015-08-18 16:21:44,409 : Key: MonthlyAdvancedPTCAmtPP
2015-08-18 16:21:44,409 : Value: 125
2015-08-18 16:21:44,409 : Key: IndividualReturnFilingStatusCd
2015-08-18 16:21:44,409 : Value: 1
2015-08-18 16:21:44,409 : Key: IRS1040
2015-08-18 16:21:44,409 : Value: 

2015-08-18 16:21:44,409 : Key: MonthlyPTCInformationGrpPP
2015-08-18 16:21:44,409 : Value: 

2015-08-18 16:21:44,409 : Key: MonthlyPremiumSLCSPAmtPP
2015-08-18 16:21:44,409 : Value: 250
2015-08-18 16:21:44,409 : Key: Filer
2015-08-18 16:21:44,409 : Value: 

2015-08-18 16:21:44,409 : Key: TotalPremiumSLCSPAmtPP
2015-08-18 16:21:44,409 : Value: 3000
2015-08-18 16:21:44,409 : Key: ResidentStateAbbreviationCdPP
2015-08-18 16:21:44,409 : Value: CA
2015-08-18 16:21:44,409 : Key: TotalPlanPremiumAmtPP
2015-08-18 16:21:44,409 : Value: 1632
2015-08-18 16:21:44,409 : Key: TotalExemptionsCnt
2015-08-18 16:21:44,409 : Value: 1
2015-08-18 16:21:44,409 : Key: TotalAdvancedPTCAmtPP
2015-08-18 16:21:44,409 : Value: 1500
2015-08-18 16:21:44,409 : Key: MonthlyPlanPremiumAmtPP
2015-08-18 16:21:44,409 : Value: 136
2015-08-18 16:21:44,409 : Key: RecipientSSNPP
2015-08-18 16:21:44,409 : Value: 555-11-2222
2015-08-18 16:21:44,409 : Key: WagesSalariesAndTipsAmt
2015-08-18 16:21:44,409 : Value: 22000
2015-08-18 16:21:44,409 : Key: MonthCdPP
2015-08-18 16:21:44,409 : Value: NOVEMBER
2015-08-18 16:21:44,409 : Key: ReturnData
2015-08-18 16:21:44,409 : Value: 

2015-08-18 16:21:44,409 : Key: PrimaryResidentStatesInfoGrpPP
2015-08-18 16:21:44,409 : Value: 

2015-08-18 16:21:44,409 : Key: SelfSelectPINGrp
2015-08-18 16:21:44,409 : Value: 

2015-08-18 16:21:44,409 : Key: ResidentStateInfoPP
2015-08-18 16:21:44,409 : Value: 

2015-08-18 16:21:44,409 : Key: Return
2015-08-18 16:21:44,409 : Value: 

2015-08-18 16:21:44,409 : Key: PrimaryBirthDt
2015-08-18 16:21:44,409 : Value: 1970-01-01
2015-08-18 16:21:44,409 : Key: ReturnHeader
2015-08-18 16:21:44,409 : Value: 

2015-08-18 16:21:44,409 : Key: AdjustedGrossIncomeAmt
2015-08-18 16:21:44,409 : Value: 22000
2015-08-18 16:21:44,409 : Key: PrimarySSN
2015-08-18 16:21:44,409 : Value: 555-11-2222
```

**XML Document**: request.xml

```
<Return xmlns="http://www.irs.gov/efile">
  <ReturnData>
    <IRS1095A uuid="a77f40a2-af31-4404-a27d-4c1eaad730c2">
      <MonthlyPTCInformationGrpPP uuid="69dc9dd5-5415-4ee4-a199-19b2dbb701be">
        <MonthlyPlanPremiumAmtPP>136</MonthlyPlanPremiumAmtPP>
        <MonthlyAdvancedPTCAmtPP>125</MonthlyAdvancedPTCAmtPP>
        <MonthCdPP>SEPTEMBER</MonthCdPP>
        <MonthlyPremiumSLCSPAmtPP>250</MonthlyPremiumSLCSPAmtPP>
      </MonthlyPTCInformationGrpPP>
      <MonthlyPTCInformationGrpPP uuid="8495fa61-0e7c-45e3-8f07-9765f4ef2fc3">
        <MonthCdPP>OCTOBER</MonthCdPP>
        <MonthlyPremiumSLCSPAmtPP>250</MonthlyPremiumSLCSPAmtPP>
        <MonthlyAdvancedPTCAmtPP>125</MonthlyAdvancedPTCAmtPP>
        <MonthlyPlanPremiumAmtPP>136</MonthlyPlanPremiumAmtPP>
      </MonthlyPTCInformationGrpPP>
      <MonthlyPTCInformationGrpPP uuid="7de1052f-6107-41da-aea4-e4495018fc80">
        <MonthlyPlanPremiumAmtPP>136</MonthlyPlanPremiumAmtPP>
        <MonthlyAdvancedPTCAmtPP>125</MonthlyAdvancedPTCAmtPP>
        <MonthlyPremiumSLCSPAmtPP>250</MonthlyPremiumSLCSPAmtPP>
        <MonthCdPP>APRIL</MonthCdPP>
      </MonthlyPTCInformationGrpPP>
      <MonthlyPTCInformationGrpPP uuid="634d5af9-51fb-42ee-a90d-5a4f421e6854">
        <MonthlyPlanPremiumAmtPP>136</MonthlyPlanPremiumAmtPP>
        <MonthCdPP>JUNE</MonthCdPP>
        <MonthlyPremiumSLCSPAmtPP>250</MonthlyPremiumSLCSPAmtPP>
        <MonthlyAdvancedPTCAmtPP>125</MonthlyAdvancedPTCAmtPP>
      </MonthlyPTCInformationGrpPP>
      <MonthlyPTCInformationGrpPP uuid="a2f7de3f-650c-4a5e-b26c-30cfd7782d6c">
        <MonthCdPP>MAY</MonthCdPP>
        <MonthlyPlanPremiumAmtPP>136</MonthlyPlanPremiumAmtPP>
        <MonthlyPremiumSLCSPAmtPP>250</MonthlyPremiumSLCSPAmtPP>
        <MonthlyAdvancedPTCAmtPP>125</MonthlyAdvancedPTCAmtPP>
      </MonthlyPTCInformationGrpPP>
      <MonthlyPTCInformationGrpPP uuid="a77f40a2-af31-4404-a27d-4c1eaad730c2">
        <MonthlyPlanPremiumAmtPP>136</MonthlyPlanPremiumAmtPP>
        <MonthlyPremiumSLCSPAmtPP>250</MonthlyPremiumSLCSPAmtPP>
        <MonthlyAdvancedPTCAmtPP>125</MonthlyAdvancedPTCAmtPP>
        <MonthCdPP>JANUARY</MonthCdPP>
      </MonthlyPTCInformationGrpPP>
      <MonthlyPTCInformationGrpPP uuid="01650aee-9d5d-4ce1-9079-ebedea3bf416">
        <MonthlyPlanPremiumAmtPP>136</MonthlyPlanPremiumAmtPP>
        <MonthlyAdvancedPTCAmtPP>125</MonthlyAdvancedPTCAmtPP>
        <MonthlyPremiumSLCSPAmtPP>250</MonthlyPremiumSLCSPAmtPP>
        <MonthCdPP>MARCH</MonthCdPP>
      </MonthlyPTCInformationGrpPP>
      <MonthlyPTCInformationGrpPP uuid="581ba189-222d-4999-aa1a-3b290666ef5f">
        <MonthlyPremiumSLCSPAmtPP>250</MonthlyPremiumSLCSPAmtPP>
        <MonthCdPP>AUGUST</MonthCdPP>
        <MonthlyPlanPremiumAmtPP>136</MonthlyPlanPremiumAmtPP>
        <MonthlyAdvancedPTCAmtPP>125</MonthlyAdvancedPTCAmtPP>
      </MonthlyPTCInformationGrpPP>
      <TotalPremiumSLCSPAmtPP>3000</TotalPremiumSLCSPAmtPP>
      <MonthlyPTCInformationGrpPP uuid="549ff57a-58dc-4365-b05c-e3e520b3e8cb">
        <MonthlyPlanPremiumAmtPP>136</MonthlyPlanPremiumAmtPP>
        <MonthlyAdvancedPTCAmtPP>125</MonthlyAdvancedPTCAmtPP>
        <MonthlyPremiumSLCSPAmtPP>250</MonthlyPremiumSLCSPAmtPP>
        <MonthCdPP>DECEMBER</MonthCdPP>
      </MonthlyPTCInformationGrpPP>
      <MonthlyPTCInformationGrpPP uuid="195836cf-32b3-4316-99d4-6b1eab31e16d">
        <MonthlyPlanPremiumAmtPP>136</MonthlyPlanPremiumAmtPP>
        <MonthCdPP>JULY</MonthCdPP>
        <MonthlyAdvancedPTCAmtPP>125</MonthlyAdvancedPTCAmtPP>
        <MonthlyPremiumSLCSPAmtPP>250</MonthlyPremiumSLCSPAmtPP>
      </MonthlyPTCInformationGrpPP>
      <MonthlyPTCInformationGrpPP uuid="c1289d91-7ce1-41ee-9c8a-f72212e82752">
        <MonthlyPlanPremiumAmtPP>136</MonthlyPlanPremiumAmtPP>
        <MonthlyAdvancedPTCAmtPP>125</MonthlyAdvancedPTCAmtPP>
        <MonthCdPP>FEBRUARY</MonthCdPP>
        <MonthlyPremiumSLCSPAmtPP>250</MonthlyPremiumSLCSPAmtPP>
      </MonthlyPTCInformationGrpPP>
      <TotalAdvancedPTCAmtPP>1500</TotalAdvancedPTCAmtPP>
      <RecipientSSNPP>555-11-2222</RecipientSSNPP>
      <MonthlyPTCInformationGrpPP uuid="50876222-165d-442a-81e0-0b05dc3c30fb">
        <MonthlyAdvancedPTCAmtPP>125</MonthlyAdvancedPTCAmtPP>
        <MonthlyPlanPremiumAmtPP>136</MonthlyPlanPremiumAmtPP>
        <MonthCdPP>NOVEMBER</MonthCdPP>
        <MonthlyPremiumSLCSPAmtPP>250</MonthlyPremiumSLCSPAmtPP>
      </MonthlyPTCInformationGrpPP>
      <TotalPlanPremiumAmtPP>1632</TotalPlanPremiumAmtPP>
    </IRS1095A>
    <IRS1040>
      <IndividualReturnFilingStatusCd>1</IndividualReturnFilingStatusCd>
      <WagesSalariesAndTipsAmt>22000</WagesSalariesAndTipsAmt>
      <TotalExemptionsCnt>1</TotalExemptionsCnt>
      <AdjustedGrossIncomeAmt>22000</AdjustedGrossIncomeAmt>
    </IRS1040>
  </ReturnData>
  <ReturnHeader>
    <SelfSelectPINGrp>
      <PrimaryBirthDt>1970-01-01</PrimaryBirthDt>
    </SelfSelectPINGrp>
    <Filer>
      <PrimarySSN>555-11-2222</PrimarySSN>
      <PrimaryResidentStatesInfoGrpPP>
        <ResidentStateInfoPP uuid="a77f40a2-af31-4404-a27d-4c1eaad730c2">
          <ResidentStateAbbreviationCdPP>CA</ResidentStateAbbreviationCdPP>
        </ResidentStateInfoPP>
      </PrimaryResidentStatesInfoGrpPP>
    </Filer>
  </ReturnHeader>
</Return>
```

Comment: I am noticing duplicate entries are skipped, it only prints out uniques example, there are multiple <MonthlyPlanPremiumAmtPP> nodes, all same except with <MonthCdPP> different

Comment: Should change the name of key with some incrementation to avoid this pb ? isnt a unicity on keys in a hashmap ?

Comment: Or just dont use a map but list of list instead

Comment: Also with list there is no key,value pair. It takes just single parameter, so I don't see that working

Answer (score 1):

You have multiple elements by the same name that are identified by their uid. Extract them by going through the XML attributes.

```
    String name = "",value = "", attrName = "";
    while(xr.hasNext()) {
        int e = xr.next();
        switch (e)
        {
            case XMLStreamReader.START_ELEMENT:
            {
                name = xr.getLocalName();
                final int attributeCount = xr.getAttributeCount();
                if(attributeCount > 0)
                {
                    attrName = xr.getAttributeName(0).getLocalPart();
                    final String attributeValue = xr.getAttributeValue(0);
                    System.out.println(name + " " + attrName + " " + attributeValue);
                }
                break;
            }
            case XMLStreamReader.CHARACTERS:
            {
                value = xr.getText();
                break;
            }
        }
    }
```

Running that gives you this

```
IRS1095A uuid a77f40a2-af31-4404-a27d-4c1eaad730c2
MonthlyPTCInformationGrpPP uuid 69dc9dd5-5415-4ee4-a199-19b2dbb701be
MonthlyPTCInformationGrpPP uuid 8495fa61-0e7c-45e3-8f07-9765f4ef2fc3
MonthlyPTCInformationGrpPP uuid 7de1052f-6107-41da-aea4-e4495018fc80
MonthlyPTCInformationGrpPP uuid 634d5af9-51fb-42ee-a90d-5a4f421e6854
MonthlyPTCInformationGrpPP uuid a2f7de3f-650c-4a5e-b26c-30cfd7782d6c
MonthlyPTCInformationGrpPP uuid a77f40a2-af31-4404-a27d-4c1eaad730c2
MonthlyPTCInformationGrpPP uuid 01650aee-9d5d-4ce1-9079-ebedea3bf416
MonthlyPTCInformationGrpPP uuid 581ba189-222d-4999-aa1a-3b290666ef5f
MonthlyPTCInformationGrpPP uuid 549ff57a-58dc-4365-b05c-e3e520b3e8cb
MonthlyPTCInformationGrpPP uuid 195836cf-32b3-4316-99d4-6b1eab31e16d
MonthlyPTCInformationGrpPP uuid c1289d91-7ce1-41ee-9c8a-f72212e82752
MonthlyPTCInformationGrpPP uuid 50876222-165d-442a-81e0-0b05dc3c30fb
ResidentStateInfoPP uuid a77f40a2-af31-4404-a27d-4c1eaad730c2
```

Use the `XMLStreamReader.CHARACTERS` constant to extract characters. A `Map<String, String>` containing the element name will not work for flattening this XML. I'd suggest using an `XPATH`.

Comment: But what about the values? I don't care for the attributes other than identifying them as unique entities for nodes of the same name

Comment: `value = xr.getText();` under `XMLStreamReader.CHARACTERS` extracts the values. Watch out for `/n`.

Comment: I see, and when you say use XPATH rather than Map<String,String> could you show an example? I'm new to this. Ultimately I'd like the Key to be an xpath such as for key 'ResidentStateInfoPP' I want to print it as '[/Return/ReturnHeader/Filer/PrimaryResidentStatesInfoGrpPP/ResidentStateInfoPP/ResidentStateAbbreviationCdPP', CA]

Comment: You're *almost* on the right track. What you need is `Return/ReturnData/IRS1095A{a77f40a2-af31-4404-a27d-4c1eaad730c2}/MonthlyPTCInformationGrpPP{69dc9dd5-5415-4ee4-a199-19b2dbb701be}/MonthlyPlanPremiumAmtPP=136`. Your callback methods should remember the hierarchy of `START_ELEMENT` at each stage. You can use a stack to remember the names and construct an xpath.

Comment: Can you show me a code example? I'm having trouble getting this to work with XPath

Comment: I'd like to put these keys and values into a Map so when I call these values I'd be able to print an associated value next to each xpath